# Apache2 Logs - Single user agent shows as an escaped string

Tags: security, apache-http-server, logging, htaccess

first time caller long time listener.

I've been playing around with hosting my own web server via Apache on an Ubuntu VM. I've been reviewing the access.log file, and noticed a discrepancy I can't find any information for. See attached image:

[image]

This request appears to have been escaped in quotes, it is the only one.

I don't know what this means, nor can I find any information about it.

Is there any setting I can change on my end to make sure the log file does not keep the '\"'?

Also, would this indicate it is a fraudulent user agent and that IP should be blacklisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing with another user, the most likely scenario seems to be the User Agent was spoofed, and in this instance, the spoofer made a mistake and passed double quotes.